# How to pass php variables to a *.js-file inside Wordpress with wp_localize_script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress plugin, that uses data from the backend to display it in the frontend.

I've got two important files. One PHP plugin file with a form, where users can submit data and one JavaScript file of another Plugin, where the data should be implemented into a dynamically generated content file.

First, I used an iframe to implement the data, which is stored in an HTML file, but this method has many disadvantages. I would like to insert the data directly with a string-variable passed from the PHP file to the JavaScript file and figured out, that wp-localize-script should do that, but I cant get it to work.

In my PHP plugin file, my code looks like this:

```
$phptestvariable = "Ausgabe der PHP-Testvariable";

function js_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_register_script("scripts", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/plugins/h5p/h5p-php-library/js/h5p.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script("scripts");
    wp_localize_script("scripts", "php_vars", $phptestvariable);
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "js_enqueue_scripts");
```

In my JavaScript file (/wp-content/plugins/h5p/h5p-php-library/js/h5p.js) the code looks like this:

```
actionBar.on('cc', function () {

    console.log(php_vars.variable);
    var dialog = new H5P.Dialog('copyrights', H5P.t('ccInfo'), php_vars , $container);
        // Übergabe Werte: Button Name, PopUp Titel, PopUp Inhalt, $container
    dialog.open();
    instance.triggerXAPI('accessed-copyright');
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens right now?

Answer (score 1):

3rd parameter of `wp_localize_script` has to be an array.
For example:

```
wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'php_vars',
    array( 
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'var_1' => 'Ausgabe der PHP-Testvariable'
    )
);
```

Then somewhere in your JS

```
alert(php_vars.var_1)
```

will display `value 1`

P.S. `ajax_url` contains and URL to make your AJAX calls in case you need that too. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) is some explanation on that.